# Maximum number of circles/ellipses in an irregular blob

Tags: python, image-processing

I am wondering, is there such algorithm/approach that can help me find the number of lobes in a binary image? the condition is as long as there is a visible necking present (green arrow)

[image: Blob with necking]

hence from this image, there are 2 lobes present, connected by that one necking point

However, in the image below, it is considered as single blob as there is no apparent necking point present

[image: Blob with no necking]

One way (that I thought of) to solve this is by trying to fit in circles/ellipses of min radius R into the blob, instead of filling it up circles/ellipses of different radii and tries to cover the whole binary image with them

Comment: As such, the question has no answer that makes sense. You can pack together a large number of them, down to a single pixel size.

Comment: I see. Perhaps, if I limit the min size of radius, I can arrive to a better result?

Comment: Would be useful to know why you want to do this.

Comment: An exact solution would require setting up an energy function related to your ellipses and how they cover the shape, and I have the feeling that minimizing that energy function might be an NP hard problem. There could be many approaches to approximate a solution, but it’s hard to pick one without knowing the constraints.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i am trying to count number of lobes in a binary image, from the picture, it is considered as 2 lobes (top and bottom circle).

Comment: That's a very very different question than the initial one ! You should show more examples and explain what you consider to be a lobe.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  you are absolutely right. Should have been more clear regarding and re-read and check this properly before posting. I shall Close/Delete this question and open a new one soon

Comment: You can just edit this one.